# Prevent DNS query for requests that were redirected using chrome.declarativeNetRequest

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I've noticed that even though requests are being redirected from `host1` to `host2` by `chrome.declarativeNetRequest` rule, `host1` is still queried for DNS.

I know this is not a bug, this level of control was not possible even before Manifest V3, but I think it should be implemented to avoid leaking information and redundant DNS requests.

Is there a place where this can be suggested?

Comment: https://crbug.com.